# replace multiple consecutive blank lines to single blank line in reading a file in c++

Tags: file, input

I am reading a text file in c++, do some changes on its data and make an output file,
the question is how could I replace multiple consecutive blank lines  to just one blank lines?, which I need this format for my output.

my data file, for an instance, is like this:

```
acument licensing


adding a name to a deed
http://Law.JustAnswer.com
http://Biztree.com

adoption deed
http://LegalSuggest.com
```

here I should change the first two blank lines to single blank line.

Comment: Have you wrote any code? Where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: yes, I take data by getline(myfile,s) and do some manipulation in rest over that. but the thing I have problem, is to check if there are multiple consecutive blank s then I should write just one of them in output. it should be done before that manipulation over lines which "s", which is right after getline. But i dont know how get the track of multiple consecutive blank lines in s when I read file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're reading the file one line at a time with something like `std::getline`.

It's very simple.  Just keep a boolean flag, initialised to `false` and update it each time.

```
if( !(lastEmpty && currentEmpty) ) output
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried your first edit code and it worked.